# Can someone take a look at m remove() method for a java LinkedList?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public boolean remove(T item) {
    int index = 0;

    if(contains(item)){
        Node<T> current = first.getNext();
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            if((current.getData()).equals(item)){
                index = i; //this will be the index of the item to be removed
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        current.setData(null);
        System.out.println(index);
        System.out.println(size);

        for(int i = index; i < size; i++){
            if(i < size){
                current.setData(current.next.getData());
                current = current.next;
            }
            if(i == size)
                current = last;
        }

        size--;

        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

the first part of the if and the following for loop finds the index of the item that is desired to be removed by running through the list until it is found. This part works.

The current item, desired to b removed is now set to null (don't think this is really necessary?)

The printing of the index and size were just for testing.

Then I have a for loop that I thought was simple enough, it sets each item to be the next item, until it reaches the end, effectively shrinking the list by one and getting rid of the desired item at its found index.

However, I'm getting null pointer exceptions at the line current.setNext(current.next). If this code only runs if i < size, then I'm not sure why this is happening. I hope I'm on the right track with this method.

If it would make it easier to help, I can post the rest of the class.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1.

```
current.setNext(current.next);
```

You're not advancing the index thus you basically set the reference to itself.

2.

Why are you calling `if(contains(item))` and then look for the item again? I'd just do it in one go.

3.

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
  if((current.getData()).equals(item)){
     index = i; //this will be the index of the item to be removed
  }
  current = current.next;
}
```

If you found the node you're still calling `current = current.next;`, so `current` will point to the node after the one you want to get. I assume you want to add a `break;` in the condition block.

4.

```
for(int i = index; i <= size; index++){
```

You should increment `i` and not `index`, otherwise the loop itself would never terminate.

5.

After your edit you have this:

```
for(int i = index; i <= size; index++){
  if(i < size){
    current.setData(current.next.getData());
    current = current.next;
  }
  ...
```

Here you have one iteration too much. Assume the list A, B, C again. `size` is 3 here and when removing B you get `index = 1`.

Now you iterate over `i = 1; i <= 3; i++`. (I assume you fixed no. 4 here)

So after the first iteration `current` will point to C and `i` will be 2. Thus you're executing the if-block again and call `current.next.getData()` which I assume will result in the NPE, since C doesn't have a next node.

Comment: oops, you're right. I've changed it to current.setData(current.next.getData());

Comment: @user2407420 as far as I can see that would duplicate the data. You need to change the node references though.

Comment: It would duplicate it, but then the next item would also be changed to the one after, until it reaches the end. It is meant to basically shift every item over one and then decrement size.

Comment: I also fixed the problem you mentioned in point 3, just caught it before I read your answer. I just added an else

Comment: Gah, how did I miss that with index++, that was right and fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You're doing `for(int i = index; i <= size; index++)` Note the `<=`. The cause for a `NullPointerException` is always the same - the reference is `null`. Debug it based on this; you know your code best.